# Scrollbars is added, but elements does not fill the page

Tags: html, css

I am working on a website, at the moment on a sign-up page. Its all perfect, right until i realize some very annoying. I have kinda 2 elements on this page. A sign up div, and an img, for the logo in the top. And it is not even close to fill the whole html page. But it still adds the SCROLL BARS, and i can scroll like 20 px up and down, and from side to side. Very annoying plz help

Comment: Upload it on some server and give the link here, can't help you without the code

Comment: A [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) would be helpful

Comment: we have to see the code, there is no way some one could help you.

Comment: Please include the CSS/HTML code snippets, so we could help to resolve your issue.

Comment: Okay guys, here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5p4Kr/ You see, i can scroll up and down which is very annoying :/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/zTZ7T/embedded/result/  is this what you want ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be fixed in two ways

Either change the width and height of the body to `auto` as:

```
html, body {   
 width: auto;   
height: auto;    

background: #11BD83;
}
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zTZ7T/)

Or as suggested by @Per Salbark add `margin : 0` to the body

```
html, body {   
 width: 100%;   
height: 100%;    
margin : 0;
background: #11BD83;
}
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zTZ7T/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You want to add `margin: 0;` to your `body`.

It's already 100% wide, and the margin pushes the width beyond the space available on screen. This causes a vertical scrollbar, and that, in turn, causes a horizontal scrollbar.